# How do crawlers parse text from webpage?

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, web-crawler

There are stanadard methods like `DOM` to selectively parse an html page, but I wonder how crawlers (from small to large ones) can detect where is the main text to be analyzed?

The main text, which will be analyzed for capturing its keywords, is mixed with menus, sidebars, footers, etc. How a crawler knows to skip keywords from menus and side parts?

I am working on a small PHP project to capture keywords from a variety of HTML pages, and I have no idea how to avoid keywords captured from side contents. Can anyone describe or at least give me a hint how to distinguish the main content from others in a HTML page?

Comment: I am not talking about search results. For example, when parsing the present page, how to recognize that the main text is my question and its answers; NOT the side bar, list of related questions, menus, StackOverflow notes, etc. I am talking about writing a crawler, not how to control the way crawlers treat my site.

Comment: Take a look at [Readability project](http://arc90.com/work/readability/), it has been ported to PHP and Python

Answer (score 2):

Sidebars, menus and footers are usually repeated on each page throughout a site. Actual content is generally unique to each page. You can use this as a guide for distinguishing actual content.

Crawlers also use complex algorithms for analysing text on a page to determine its weight as content, and they tend not to share their secrets.

There is no quick and easy way, crawler developers have to come up with their own innovative methods and collectively employ those to get an overall picture of a page's content.

Comment: you're right! crawler technology is really advanced and complicated, but there should be some tricks for small and mid-sized crawlers too.

Answer (score 0):

If the content is textual, You can assume that the main content of the page is where the word density is relatively higher.

This means the main content of the page which is relevant to search engines -- the main content of the page is inside the dom elements mostly divs where the number of literals including tags like p,em,b, etc etc which are essentially for text formatting, is higher or above a threshold.

I shall start off with the following logic

get all the tags used in the webpage.

I shall note down the dom elements where the content is formed of only literals and formatting tags like p,em,b,li,ul and also anchor tags.

I would leave divs containing only anchor tags and assume they are for navigational purposes.

Now out of all these choose the dom elements where the number is above a particular threshold.

This threshold value varies from website to website,which you can take as avg(literals found in the div having highest literals across all pages of a site of a particular url structure)

The algorithm has to learn during its course.

Comment: sorry, it was typo; I meant `word density`. How to measure the word density in the pool of html tags?